# Android - kotlin - passing commands to outputstream doesn't work everytime

Tags: android, kotlin, stream

I am developing with Kotlin an Android app which uses an SDR USB dongle and an rtl-tcp connection.
I am using the driver rtl-tcp-andro from Martin Marinov : https://github.com/martinmarinov/rtl_tcp_andro-

I have managed to get data from the inputstream and to send commands through the outputstream but it doesn't work everytime. The commands are 5 bytes array consisting of a one byte command and 4 bytes data. The driver tells me when it gets certain commands (like gain change or frequency correction but not frequency change).

So, after a successful connection to the driver, to test the outputstream, I have made a loop as follow :

```
//TOP DECLARATION
var correctionFreqSdr = 10


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode != 1234) return
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            socket = Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234)
            socket?.tcpNoDelay = true
            inputStream = socket?.getInputStream()
            outputStream = socket?.getOutputStream()

            for (i in 0 until 15) {
               val rnds = 10
               correctionFreqSdr += rnds
               val commandArrayFreqCorrection = ByteArray(5)
               commandArrayFreqCorrection[0] = RTL_TCP_COMMAND_SET_FREQ_CORR.toByte()
               commandArrayFreqCorrection[1] = (correctionFreqSdr shr 24 and 0xff).toByte()
               commandArrayFreqCorrection[2] = (correctionFreqSdr shr 16 and 0xff).toByte()
               commandArrayFreqCorrection[3] = (correctionFreqSdr shr 8 and 0xff).toByte()
               commandArrayFreqCorrection[4] = (correctionFreqSdr and 0xff).toByte()

               outputStream?.write(commandArrayFreqCorrection)
               delay(200) // give some time to write command. I am not sure it is 
                             necessary
               outputStream?.flush()
               }
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { //just to make sure that the loop is over
            tv_text.text = "fin de la loop changment de gain"
            delay(3000)
            }
            outputStream?.flush()
            outputStream?.close()
            inputStream?.close()
            socket!!.close()
            socket = null

         }

 } else {
            // something went wrong, and the driver failed to start
            if (resultCode == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "resultcode is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            } else {
                val errmsg = data!!.getStringExtra("detailed_exception_message")
                Log.i("resultcode2", resultCode.toString())
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, errmsg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

The drivers tells me that it gets the frequency correction the first X times (if the loop happens 10 times, it works everytime but if the loop goes to 20 or more, it might works only the first 6 or 7 times, sometimes only the 3 first times) and I don't understand why.

Is it an issue with the stream ? Is it an issue with coroutines ?
I have tried with a thread instead of coroutine, but it did the same.
Does anyone know what the issue is ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, I have been working on it for a few days but asking the question gave me the answer. I need to deal with the inputstream. It is like if I don't "consume" the inputstream, it get stucks in the pipe and the outputstream can't get through. So I added another coroutines which continuously takes the inputstream and just throw it away immediately and that solved my issue. I leave the question here as it may help somebody else in the future.